# How to add comment block to methods in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Is there an easy of adding a comment block (Javadoc style) to every method in an Eclipse project and possibly classes so I can fill in them later?

Comment: Yes, you can right-click on a method declaraion, then click `Source > Generate Element comment`. Nevertheless, it is not a good idea to add the documentation later... this never works. Document each method before you implement it or at least immediately after implementing it!

Comment: I realized that, but better late that never :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As suggested you can do it method-per-method (Source -> Generate element comment) or `ALT+SHIFT+J` but I find it a very bad idea. Comments are only useful when they give an additional information. When you feel more information is needed add it.

Having comments on setters like "*sets the value*" or worse automatically generated comments  it not useful at all.

Comment: +1; auto-generating docs for *everything* is ultimate counter-productive due to the excess noise.

Comment: This method adds comment blocks to class variables and methods. However it just adds a normal /* */ on top of each method with no other details. I remember using program to add PHPdoc style comment to every function in PHP projects with many details. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: "sets the value" type of comments actually worsen the code readability.

Answer (score 12):

To add a comment over the method ***select getUser*** or ***take the cursor before getUser*** and press ALT + SHIFT + J It will add the comment on top of your method

```
/*
* @param
* @return User
*/
public User getUser();
```

Comment: @hirosht yes, it is

Answer (score 8):

Under

> Window | Preferences | Java | Code Style | Code Templates

you will find 2 features:

- Automatically add comments for new methods or types
- Comments | Methods | Edit...

You can edit the generated comment block by use of eclipse variables or your static Javadoc text.

Comment: In which way I am able to apply method comment into the source code? For example in (Source ->  Generate element comment), we could generate so to say class comment, are there some quick way we could have "Generate method comment".

Answer (score 5):

simple thing is ,you just type /** and press **Enter**  on the top of method ,where you want generate comment .it automatically generates the element comment .No need to go for long Key ins.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for this

http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Mac Users: <kbd>⌃</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>

- Option - ⌥
- Control - ⌃

Windows Users:  <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>

PS: Make sure you have [JAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/) plugin installed

Answer (score 0):

use these following steps an you will do it easily.
in eclipse go to Project -> generate javadoc ->press enter and then select your project to be documented.